# ZipInputSream in the end of file write [][][][][][][][][][]....?

Tags: java, zip, inputstream

In Eclipse when I'm trying to display content of files from zip in the end of each file is [][][][][][][][][][]. Can anybody explain this?

```
def uploadTheme(String themeName, def inputStream) {

    def themeNameUp = themeName.toUpperCase()
    def themeKey = this.prefix + themeNameUp

    if (redisService.exists(themeKey) && inputStream) {
        ZipInputStream zipFile = new ZipInputStream(inputStream)
        ZipEntry zipEntry = zipFile.nextEntry

        while (zipEntry) {
            def key = zipEntry.name

            if (key.startsWith(this.widgetPrefix) || key.startsWith(this.templatePrefix)) {
                byte[] data = new byte[4096]

                StringBuffer zipContent = new StringBuffer()
                int length = zipFile.read(data, 0, data.size())                                     

                while (length != -1) {
                    zipContent << new String(data)

                    length = zipFile.read(data, 0, data.size())
                }

                if (key.endsWith(":data")) {
                    def prevData = redisService.hget(themeKey, key)

                    if (prevData) {
                        historyService.addHistory(themeNameUp + ":" + key[0..-6], prevData)
                    }
                }

                redisService.hset(themeKey, key, zipContent.toString())
            }

            zipFile.closeEntry()
            zipEntry = zipFile.nextEntry
        }

        zipFile.close()
    }
```

Comment: You're trying to display binary content?

Comment: In files is just a text and when I'm trying do display text there is [][][][[][][][][][].......

Comment: You mean you're displaying files that have been extracted from a zip?

Comment: yes, text from files

Comment: Show your code, and maybe a screenshot of how the contents look like.

Comment: this is code:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25603285/java-groovy-java-util-zip-read-cant-read-zip

Comment: when I display zipContent then I see [][][][][]...

Comment: This code does not compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
zipContent << new String(data)
```

should be

```
zipContent << new String(data, 0, length)
```

as length is the number of what is actually read. At the end length is smaller than data's size.

Be aware, that the string created:

- uses the default platform encoding, as you pass no extra parameter for the encoding,
- only works for a single byte encoding, as you pass an arbitrary cut byte sequence.